# jQuery Не работает $(this).css()

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не работает?

```
$(this).сss("background-color", "#345253");
```

Вот пример кода, где оно не работает:
https://jsfiddle.net/ufrb8x5p/4/

Консоль пишет:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).сss is not a function at
>   HTMLParagraphElement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что у вас там не `сss`, а `css`.

В вашем примере `с` - это [U+0441 символ](https://unicode-table.com/en/0441/), а не [U+0063](https://unicode-table.com/en/0063/). Короче, русская "с", а не английская.

Comment: блин, тупость такая, а я все перепроверил а 100 раз, а перепечатать не подумал, спасибо большое